# count unique email addresses which are shared by multiple consumers

Tags: mysql

I need a  query to find all unique email addresses shared by multiple consumers.

The table looks like

```
email2consumer| email
1| email1
2| email2
3| email1
4| email3
```

tried count distinct and group but the results are 0

```
SELECT email2consumer _cid, count(distinct id) num
FROM tab_email_address
GROUP BY _cid HAVING num > 1;
```

> Empty set (10.65 sec)

Comment: Can you edit back the question? Can't understand what you are trying to say

Comment: Please edit post with table structure along with dummy data if possible and expected result. Also mention your efforts.
In the query specified in question, what is email2consumer_cid, id, _cid?

Comment: change your `GROUP BY` to `email` instead of `_cid`. You are looking to find emails having more than one consumer

Answer (score 1):

If you need to find email addresses used by more than one users, you can use the following query.

```
select email from tab_email_address group by email having count(email2consumer) > 1
```

One can learn more about it at [Group By tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx) and [MySQL Aggregate (Group By) reference doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

Comment: I guess the best SO action from your side is to upvote helpful answers and accept the answer which served as correct solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This will select unique emails that appear more than once in the consumer emails table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(email)
FROM tab_email_address 
GROUP BY email
HAVING count(email) > 1
```

Comment: Since we’re already grouping by on email, we can skip distinct.